# How is the passport control situation in Paris CDG Airport?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, paris, event-based-effects, cdg

After the Paris Attacks on November 13, France's President declared a state of emergency lasting three months. I guess this implies exhaustive security measures in this airport.

If you have just happened to travel through Paris CDG after November 13, did it take long to pass through the security controls and/or passport migration controls?

I am asking this, since I will fly to Scandinavia and I will make my plane change at Paris CDG. I will have one hour. Last time (months ago) it was quick and fine. I would like to know how the situation there is now. I am non EU citizen.

Are police passport controls making you spend more time answering questions?

As far as I have experienced, they usually ask you what you will do, who you will be staying with, to show them your round trip ticket, to show your bank account saldo or money… If someone also knows if they are asking for something else.

I just want to get everything necessary with me so I can make it to the next flight without any delay (I have to move from Terminal 2E Porte L to Terminal 2D).

Comment: I haven't been to CDG since the attacks so I will let someone else answer but the state of emergency does not imply any special security measures at airports (the government does not need any special legal authority for that) and as far as I can tell the focus has been on *internal* borders within the Schengen area (which were previously unattended) and not on *external* borders.

Comment: @Relaxed There is talk of having more detailed checks of arriving EU citizens (eg scanning the passport, rather than just looking vaguely at it and waving you through), but I'm not sure if that has started happening in CDG or not

Comment: @Gagravarr True but that would be illegal at the moment, that's a proposal in front of the EU council but it needs to be formally approved. It's not part of the law passed last week or the 1955 Act governing the state of emergency.

Comment: @Relaxed The UK has requirements for 100% machine scanning of arriving EU citizen passports, and I think that some other EU countries might do too (Netherlands perhaps?). Others often just look at the passport then give it back without scanning it, which means they can't check it against lists. It'll slow things down if they start 100% scanning, would take 2-3x as long in my experience. I don't know enough on the rules to know what, if anything, is needed to start 100% scanning where not already done

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, indeed, that's what the discussions are about but it's not part of the French “state of emergency”. The rules I am referring to are defined in the Schengen Borders code so they don't apply to the UK. Right now, these checks are not supposed to be systematic. I don't think it would be legal for France to start doing it right away. But I also don't think anybody would dare complain if it did. However, what's being discussed now is making it mandatory Schengen-wide and not only scanning/checking passports against lists of stolen documents but also against list of wanted persons.

Comment: @Gagravarr it should be noted that the normal Schengen "minimum check" comprises database lookup to catch lost, stolen, or fraudulent documents.  Granted, people may not have been doing that, but starting to do it requires no change in policy or legislation.  "[The] minimum check shall consist of a rapid and straightforward verification, where appropriate by using technical devices and by consulting, in the relevant databases, information exclusively on stolen, misappropriated, lost and invalidated documents, of the validity of the document [...]."

Answer (score 2):

Last time I went through was before Nov 13 but it still took significantly longer than an hour. CDG waiting times depend heavily on traffic, time of day and attitude of the staff.

The only saving grace is that it's a busy airport with lots of European flights so if you miss your connection, there is a good chance that there is another flight soon after.